# Как получить siblings() по атрибуту

Tags: javascript, jquery

код html

```
<ul >
    <li data-depth="0" >1</li>
    <li data-depth="1" >2</li>
    <li data-depth="1" >3</li>
    <li data-depth="0" >4</li>
</ul>
```

javascript

```
var item //в этой переменной находится <li data-depth="1" >3</li>
```

мне из него  надо получить `<li data-depth="0" >1</li>`
пытаюсь сделать так

```
var classDepth=item.attr("data-depth");
if(classDeptch>0){
   var siblingItemDepht=classDeptch-1
   var parent=item.siblings('[data-depth='+siblingItemDepht+']');
}
```

Comment: `Depth != Deptch != Depht` :)

Comment: как Вы из двух, отняв один, получите ноль?

Comment: вы написали в коде точно так? 
var classDepth=item.attr(data-depth); 
или?
var classDepth=item.attr("data-depth");

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan второй вариант просто код не совсем живой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

страно но вот так получилось

```
if(classDeptch>0){
       var siblingItemDepht = Number(classDeptch)-Number(1);
       var parent=item.siblings('[data-depth='+siblingItemDepht+']');
      console.log(parent);
    }
```

https://codepen.io/sirgalas/pen/pPBWyy видимо приходило не число